# relationships between instantiated list types

Tags: python, python-typing

I'd like to check if a type object is a `typing.List` regardless of the container type. Is there a simple way to check? I have tried

```
>>> isinstance(typing.List[int], typing.List)
False
>>> typing.List[int] == typing.List
False
```

but neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible starting with Python 3.8 by using [`typing.get_origin()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin):

```
>>> typing.get_origin(typing.List[int]) == list
True
```